# User comments count

Tags: php, comments

I found this code on the web. That was very useful but I need to display the User Comments Count near the Users' name.
What can I do?

```
$allUsers = get_users('orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');

$users = array();

// Remove subscribers from the list as they won't write any articles
foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
{
    if(!in_array( 'administrator', $currentUser->roles ))
    {
    $users[] = $currentUser;
}
}

foreach($users as $user)
            {
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?>

<?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, '128' ); ?>
}
```

Comment: is the "User comments count" already stored in the user informations ? If so, you need to access it, but it depends on how the `$user` is made, do you have the code about the class of user ?

Comment: Mmm I think the problem it's me. ;)
I don't know how to implement the comment count function in the code I posted before. 
Because I tried another code: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29417/show-top-commenters-without-using-a-plugin

And it works for the comments count. But in this case the link to the user page doesn't work.

I explain: I would like display a list of users with link to author page, avatar and comments count. Better if is all sort by comments count. Like a page of more active users.

Do you think is possible? :) I'm sorry but I am not an expert of PHP